# How do I get Node to break on a stack overflow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

Let's say I have a JS script like the following:

```
function recurse() {
    return recurse();
}
recurse();
```

If I run `node recurse.js`, it will of course fail with a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

How do I get a debugger (for example, running in VS Code) to break before this exception happens, so I can see what's in the stack? I can attach a breakpoint, but it would take forever to hit this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Maximum call stack size exceeded` is an exception like any other. Wrap the call in a try/catch, and add a stop point inside the catch block, like so:

```js
function recurse() {
    return recurse()
}

try {
  recurse()
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e) // <- stop here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd love if this was possible without modifying the code, but this is a perfectly workable solution.